# Submission confirmation step in the app approval form of Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.3

**This is the last section in the approval form for the extended permissions :**

[image]

I want to know why these url's are mentioned here, will Facebook download/test the apps from live app stores or the one which I have submitted above in the same form.

Comment: Depends on whether you upload IPA/APK files for them to test, or provide app store ids/package names. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/how-to-submit#completesubmissionform

Answer (score 0):

Yes these apps are tested to make sure you are following Facebook policies properly. If you upload the apps then they will be reviewed else those platforms will be ignored and only the ones you submit will be reviewed.